# Linux on Windows10 -- possible to run red hat flavor?

Tags: linux, windows-10

I just set up ubuntu on windows 10. Wow! Cool!

We run CentOS at work. I would strongly like to have Fedora, or some Red Hat flavor as my Linux subsystem.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Fedora is supposed to be avail in the MS Store, but it is held up for some reason.

The threads related to this are :

- here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2584
- links to vote on reddit, twitter and user voice are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3288

We need fedora support. Our use of WSL is on hold until Fedora or CentOS is in the MS Store. (All our devs are Win10 Pro users.)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get a Linux build into WSL: Get it from Microsoft Store, or build it yourself.

When a certain Linux distro is not available on Windows Store, you can build one yourself. To find out how, and download the needed tools, visit:

- ["Creating a Custom Linux Distro for WSL"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/build-custom-distro). *Docs*. Microsoft (27 March 2018).

Of course, Microsoft has already announced that Fedora will soon be available on Windows Store too.